# How to detect element inner elements by id using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to detect elements inner elements reference by id using javascript ?

I have 3 elements `<div>` like this, I want to detect `<span id="inner">` inner `<div id="outer_3">` exists or not ?

in this code, Answer will show `not`

How can i do that?

```
<div id="outer_1">
    <span id="inner">
    </span>
</div>

<div id="outer_2">
    <span id="inner">
    </span>
</div>

<div id="outer_3">
</div>
```

Comment: 1. is don't used to same id used to class for multiple case or used diffrent id

Comment: What did you tried? Where is the JavaScript that is not working? Can you provide some code or a working JsFiddle?

Comment: This is an very valid use case to use JQuery if you use JQuery you can use these `$('#outer_id').find('> *')` or `$('#outer_id').children() `

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have duplicate ID values in HTML.  This is considered an HTML violation and many libraries will not work properly with that.  You should use a class instead for any element that there will be more than one of:

```
<div id="outer_1">
    <span class="inner">
    </span>
</div>

<div id="outer_2">
    <span class="inner">
    </span>
</div>

<div id="outer_3">
</div>
```

You can then reference either a selector like:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".inner")
```

to select all .inner elements.

Or, you can combine that with a parent id to select only some elements such as:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#outer_1 .inner")
```

Comment: @devicrepoyihut - so either get yourself a library that makes selector queries work on such an ancient version of IE (like jQuery or Sizzle) or code a specific query using a combination of `document.getElementById()` and `document.getElementsByClassName()`.  Your question is not specific about what exactly you want in this regard and it is now extremely rare for people to support IE7.

Comment: @devicrepoyihut - Or convince yourself or someone else that it is not worth it to support IE7 any more.  By some measures, the market share of IE7 is less than 0.5% these days.